# Slow or no access to /home folder both from Nautilus and terminal

Tags: mount, nautilus

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on 64bit. I recently mounted my /home folder as a separate partition on my hard drive (SSD).
Now occasionally, I experience that upon trying access my home folder in Nautilus, nothing will show, but the loading wheel in bottom right is turning endlessly. 
Likewise in terminal, *ls* and general try to access in that case does not work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Faulty cables maybe? You could try to replace the SSD's cables... Not sure, just a guess.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that too., but then again, everything was working fine before I mounted it.  ... Oh, just remembered that I also have cifs network shared mounted in my fstab... that might be a potential culprit too I assume